# creating a symbolic link inside a docker container from a docker host

Tags: bash, shell, docker

I have a script on the docker host that i want to run and create symbolic links inside its containers. However, i cannot seem to get the symbolic link created when i run my script below:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A containers

while IFS== read -r key value; do
    containers[$key]=${value}
S=$(sudo docker exec -t $key ln -s /srv/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf);
done < "/opt/containers.txt"
```

The weird thing is that when i run the command outside the script directly in the terminal, it actually works. E.g.,

```
sudo docker exec -t db-test-1 ln -s /srv/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

So not sure why it won't run in the script. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For testing, you can see if isolating the command (here ln) in its own shel helps:

```
 S=$(sudo docker exec -t $key /bin/sh -c "ln -s /srv/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf");
```